# This should be int, why are we using %s then?

Tags: c, string, casting, cs50

I'm going through the CS50 exercises and I don't understand this piece of code. All it does it take a positive integer as input and then printf. So in `main()` we're saving the input in `int i`.

In the next step int i is used as a parameter/argument(?) for the function get_positive_int ("string prompt").

Why is it a string? How is this possible? I'd have thought typecasting would have to be used for this to happen...

Please feel free to correct me, I'm lost.

```
// Abstraction and scope

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_positive_int(string prompt);

int main(void)
{
    int i = get_positive_int("Positive integer: ");
    printf("%i", i);
}

// Prompt user for positive integer
int get_positive_int(string prompt)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("%s", prompt);
    }
    while (n < 1);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: *"int i is used as a parameter/argument(?) for the function `get_positive_int`"* - no, it's not. `int i` is used to store the return value of `get_positive_int`

Comment: `"Positive integer: "` is the argument here. It gets passed to the `string prompt` parameter.

Comment: What is `get_int()`? This code is not shown.

Comment: @Lee It is CS50 specific.

Comment: Can you post the code for "get_int()" ? otherwise all we can do is speculate. inputting values can be done with "scanf"

Comment: @WilliamDussault Please don't recommend `scanf` to beginners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the next step int i is used as a parameter/argument(?) for the function get_positive_int ("string prompt").

Not quite.

`i` *receives* the value returned from `get_positive_int`.  The *string* `"Positive integer"` is the *argument* to `get_positive_int`.  `get_positive_int` passes that string (`prompt`) on to `get_int`, which does the actual work of writing the prompt string to standard output and reading the input you type in.

`get_int` obviously calls `vprintf`.  All the `*printf` functions require a *format string* to tell them how many additional arguments to expect, what their type is, and how their values should be formatted for output.  In this particular case, we're telling `vprintf` to expect a single argument of type `string` (`char *`).

You can write more complex prompts for `get_int`, such as

```
i = get_int( "Enter the %d'th name: ", count );
```

If count is `5`, then the prompt will be written as

```
Enter the 5'th name:
```

`get_int` then calls C's input functions (`fgets`, `fscanf`, whatever) to read and parse what you type in and make sure it's a valid integer.

<gratuitous rant>

The CS50 library abstracts away most of the gorier details of C I/O and string handling, which is nice, but in the process leaves you *absolutely unprepared* for the reality of text processing in C - it's a *lot* harder than CS50 makes it look.

Once you're done with CS50, throw away *everything* it taught you about strings and I/O and find a decent C reference manual.  Be prepared to start over from the beginning.

</gratuitous rant>

Comment: Agreed, John. Abstraction isn't helpful in the long run. I think I understand now. `get_int` formats the string `prompt` to a valid int, saving it in variable n which is the return value of function  `get_positive_int` and stored in `int i` inside `main()`.

Comment: @she_roar: `get_int` simply writes `prompt` to standard output (your terminal) as a string - *what you type in response* is what gets parsed and converted to an `int` value, and that's what `get_int` returns.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://man.cs50.io/3/get_int), `get_int` formats the prompt like `printf`. So the `%s` here is the format string to `printf`, and the second parameter (`prompt`) is the string which is printed by the `%s`.

In other words, the format string here is used only for output. There is no need to specify a format string for the input (like for `scanf`) because the function already knows that it's inputting an `int`.

Comment: as a beginner i need you to pinpoint it exactly. ``prompt``is the second parameter. what then is the first? it looks to me like there's only one.

Comment: @she_roar The parameters here work the same way as `printf`, if you are familiar with that. The first parameter is the format string `"%s"`, and this determines the types of the other parameters. `%s` means that the next parameter is a string.

Comment: wait. so in this context: `get_int("%s", prompt);` --> the first argument should be `%s`and the second argument `prompt`, right?